# QBoxLayout with stretchable separator

Tags: qt, qt4

do anybody know how to create a stretchable separator between two Widgets in a `QBoyLayout`?

So that the user can easily change the stretch factor for the cols/rows.

Something like that you can see in the picture:

[image: stretchable]

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a [QSplitter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsplitter.html) would fit best for your need. You can click and drag it to adjust how much space each widget gets.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [Splitter Layout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-layouts.html#splitter-layouts):

> Another common way to manage the layout of objects on a form is to
>   place them in a splitter. These splitters arrange the objects
>   horizontally or vertically in the same way as normal layouts, but also
>   allow the user to adjust the amount of space allocated to each object.